What are some ways of differentiating bot transactions from normal users?
I'm looking into a project this week that was suspected of using bots to manipulate volume on a token launch on Base network to determine how fair the launch was and am unsure of how to go about this part of the investigation.
I'm considering heuristics like finding average gas paid/tx frequency/number of failed txs, and comparing these factors to a token launch that I know was organic. I'm well versed in onchain data but don't have much experience with bots, or ways a team might utilize them or try to obfuscate their use.
Any insight on factors to look for in determining the extent that transactions might have been automated or methods/tools that could make this easier would be appreciated.
Context: Token in question spiked fees on Base over 500x after launch. Speculation was team used bots which may have competed with MEVs, or potential price oracle manipulation, so I'll be going back to look at activity shortly after launch.

Quick question, you say "EVM bots" and you added the tag [mev] to your post. Did you mean MEV bots? Just because they are different things. Whether you are looking for MEV bots transactions, or bots that aim to manipulate the volume you would proceed very differently

@Mouradif Oops I'll update tags. MEV may be relevant, but asking about botted txs.
